# A fast fadeIn for the first time after the page loads

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have made a tooltip using jquery. But the for first time (after the page loads properly), the tooltip appears without a delay even when I have applied a delay of duration of 500 ( milliseconds i suppose ? ). Why does this happens so?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="file://C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input").focus(function(){
                $("#div").fadeIn(500).css("background-color","#B0B0B0");
            });
            $("input").blur(function(){
                $("#div").fadeOut(500).css("background-color","#B0B0B0");

            });
            $("input").keyup(function(){
                $("#div").html($("input").val());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:150px">
        <input type="text" style="width:100%;border-radius:4px;border:1px solid #808080;padding:1%;font-family:calibri"/>
        <div id="div" style="color:#FFF;font-family:calibri;min-height:20px;border-radius:4px;padding:1%;word-wrap:break-word"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: probably stupid comment but you did set your div to display:none in your css but just forgot to put it in your code snippet right ?

Comment: Because you've styled it to be visible by default? Try setting `display:none` on your div so that it starts hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide it first. I'd recommend doing it using JS like this

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $("#div").hide()
    $("#div").fadeIn(500).css("background-color","#B0B0B0");
});
```

This way if the user has JS disabled, he'll still see the div, just without the fade-in effect.

Answer (score 3):

You have to hide it with `display:none` to start off.

```
style="display:none";
```

You then bring it into view with your animation.

```
<div id="div" style="display:none;color:#FFF;font-family:calibri;min-height:20px;border-radius:4px;padding:1%;word-wrap:break-word"></div>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266940/1624960) that is better to hide through Javascript for progressive enhancment but the theory is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because You Haven't Hide it and it already shown.

Add this line to your script in document ready function:

```
$("#div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the item to display none, and then on page load create a fadeIn(500) even for the item.

Additionally, you should consider cleaning up your jquery. Example:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    var $div = $('#div');

    $('input').on({
        focus: function(){
            $div.fadeIn(500).css({backgroundColor:"#B0B0B0"});
        },
        blur: function(){
            $div.fadeOut(500).css({backgroundColor:"#B0B0B0"});
        },
        keyup: function(){
            $div.html($(this).val());
        },
        load: function(){
            $div.fadeIn(500);
        },
    });
});
```

Not tested, but something along those lines should work.